# how do I programmatically create web context?

Tags: java, spring, web-applications

```
<context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>classpath:spring/applicationContext.xml, classpath:spring/hibernateContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I have this config in web.xml file in my web application. How do I create the context configuration programmatically? Is this possible to change classpath to an absolute path like this `/home/my/dir/spring/applicationContext.xml`?

Comment: You means [java based configuration in spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch03s11.html)?

Answer (score 0):

By implementing WebApplicationInitializer. You can find more details about it here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean creating web context dynamically, you can not it is created by server

if you mean spring context, it can be created using various implementations of ApplicationContext
http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/intro-to-ioc-creating-a-spring-application.html

however what I understand is you are using spring in web domain not as a standalone application hence you need to configure DispatcherServlet from spring
http://www.coderanch.com/t/567684/Spring/contextConfigLocation

now if you want to configure it dynamically or create dynamically are two things, configuration can be done using replacing properties using propertyplaceholders and creation can be done using ApplicationContext mentioned above